# How to get AWS to interact with a self hosted webpage?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a webpage running on my raspberry using node.js. The webpage has a simple login and after logging in I can control some hardware. The login in is using BCrypt and a mongoDB locally hosted.

I'm using below code to access a specific page, and from there I can send POST commands.

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
// do code (function call)
}
```

How can I setup AWS to communicate with my server and potentially access the function call?

How should I store my login information to my server in AWS?

/ Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your tags, you just want to use aws lambda.

You create end points in your node app ran on raspberry PI. Make sure you enable cors so that other servers can also make requests to your raspberry server.

When you have your endpoints all set up you can use aws lambda to make requests to your server. Lambdas are node instances, so all you need to do is make node http requests to the endpoints you created. Now what triggers your lambdas depends on what you want to do, just set up events accordingly.

If you want to call some function in your raspberry pi simply create an endpoint which calls that function and then aws lambda does a request to that endpoint, thus aws calls your local functions.

Same with logging in. I assume you use tokens to authorize requests to your server. Since you are making requests from lambdas and not a client, you can't use cookies/local storage to save the token. You will have to use some aws storage service, rds/s3/dynamodb/etc.

If you are open to changing your current web app architecture I suggest looking into using AWS IoT Platform. It seems like a perfect fit to set up your rasberry pi communication with AWS.

Description of IoT Platform:

> AWS IoT is a managed cloud platform that lets connected devices easily and securely interact with cloud applications and other devices. AWS IoT can support billions of devices and trillions of messages, and can process and route those messages to AWS endpoints and to other devices reliably and securely.

Guide how to set it up on raspberry pi with javascript:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-sdk-node.html

Comment: That link seems to be very interesting. Currently I'm learning and exploring nodejs so I don't mind change the current setup. Currently I'm working on the lirc_web library to get web access to my remote controls in the home. On top of that I add a loginpage to have the webpage secure when accessing it external. Next step for me is to connect the Echo dot to have voice control. Based on the link I think the approach will be to add an overlaying AWS-IoT API to my nodejs function calls, that is bypassing my local login strategy?

Comment: Yeah. IoT platform gives it's own authorization service. I suggest looking into diagram on this page: https://aws.amazon.com/iot-platform/how-it-works/ You would move your login page from being hosted on raspberry pi to it's own application, and then after logging into that application you can use IoT Platform tools to work with the device.

Comment: Will try to give it a go tomorrow. I think I will decide my tasks into 3 steps for now: 1 finish the local login strategy. 2 implement AWS IoT and connect to my device without any login page. 3. Comebine all information. Doing some research I found this page which will go very well with your suggestion to getting started: https://blog.louisborsu.be/aws-iot-getting-started-tutorial-with-nodejs/

Comment: Just a quick question: when you mention hosting my login page in a different location, do you refer to instanciate two apps in one js file something like:
var app1 = require("./app1");
var app2 = require("./app2");